# Publisher policy redirection not working

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, publisher-policy

I am learning the redirection of assembly using publisher policy file. Did the following:

- I have a DLL called Dependency which is a signed one and had it registered in the GAC.
- While registering, the assembly version  is 1.0.0.1.
- I developed a test client (Consumer) and referred the same version and built it and ran it once.
- Changed the AssemblyVersion to 1.0.0.2 for Dependency DLL
- Created a publisher policy file as shown below

[image]

- Registered the new version in GAC
- Used Al.EXE like to generate the policy assembly as shown below:

  D:\Test> al  /link:policy.config /out:policy.1.0.Dependency.dll /keyfile:....\keyfile.snk /platform:x86
- I made sure that I am using X86 config only in both the Consumer and Dependency
- Even after registering the policy assembly, I still see the older version (1.0.0.1) being used by the consumer and the policy config redirection didn't takes place.
- I tried to use Fusion log viewer but didn't see any failures of redirection

Please help me by guiding me what I am missing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For sure is a silly suggestion, but... have you tried to substitute your bindingRedirect section with this one?

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.1-1.0.0.2" newVersion="1.0.0.2" />

Comment: Hi HuroSwords, It didn't work either :(

Comment: And what if you delete the `<?xml...?>` tag line? At all documentation that I found doesn't appear this section in a publisher policy file...

Comment: hi! Thank you. I got it worked after changing the culture info to neutral. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved after I changed the culture info to neutral. I had it as en-US :(
Found this when the local app.config redirection was not working either.